# how to search files which contains some string in macOS

Tags: macos, search

I want to search files by string in macOS, now I am using this command:

```
grep -r "docker/build-push-action@v2" .
```

this command is very slow, is there any better way to search string from files in macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mdfind`.

`mdfind` is Spotlight search for the CLI.  It makes use of Spotlight’s indexed search database for super fast results.

The syntax would be

```
mdfind [-onlyin directory] “foobar query“
```

You can more details on this macOS builtin utility from the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/mdfind.html)